# How to read/open PPT files in Android?

Tags: android, ms-office, powerpoint

**[This question may be duplicate, but i din't find what i am looking for]**

[Read][How can we open files like ppt, doc, pps, rtf, etc. in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573825/how-can-we-open-files-like-ppt-doc-pps-rtf-etc-in-android)

I am having PPT files. In my app, i have a list view which display the PPT file list available in my private app folder. In click of particular file, i want to open corresponding PPT file for reading in my App.

The App which i am creating is just like collection of PPTs and reading them one by one.

Please provide any API/Example/Links.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use other application to open your ppt files , Make sure that file location you are providing is accessible to other application. Try with following :

```
 final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file); 
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"); 

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    if(list.size() > 0)
       startActivity(context, intent);
```

Available application will be shown to user and user can choose application which can open.

Comment: is there any way to open those files in my app itself.

Comment: No, you need to implement whole functionality. As in windows we Ms office to open spread sheet and docs,in same way we need some application which provide that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void openPPT(final String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri ;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
            } else {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Application not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use above code is useful for read and open ppt file in android use fileprovider for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M  add Provider path in Android Manifext.